# UWP C# Moving PivotItem to different index

Tags: c#, uwp, pivotitem, itemcollection

I have this Pivot control, loaded with PivotItems.
It's all good except that I want to be able to dynamically reorder the PivotItems, **without** cloning the PivotItems.

The problem is that the ItemCollection of the Pivot control does not seem to be able to do that. I can insert a different PivotItem, but not one that already exists at a different index (`System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range`).

I also tried `myPivot.Items.RemoveAt(currentIndex)` followed by  `myPivot.Items.Insert(targetIndex, tabToMove)` but this sometimes produces `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800F1000): No installed components were detected. Element is already the child of another element`.

Ideas?

Comment: Do you use the `ItemsSource` property to add the PivotItem? How about modify the data source collection? Could you provide more code to clarify your issue? What is your xaml and code behind?

Comment: @Breeze Liu - I am not using ItemsSource.  The PivotItem elements are added programmatically at runtime using `rootPivot.Items.Insert(...)`.
Unfortunately, the code is too large for me to post.

Comment: Please try to simplify your project to provide a simple reproducible project so that I can work on your direction.